# Библиотека sip client для python

Tags: python, sip, voip

Несколько дней назад надо мной постала такая задача: реализовать приём/набор дзвонков используя sip client. Начал я с поиска библиотеки для sip client, желательно на python, сервер использую внешний от популярного сервиса. После нескольких часов поисков я нашёл библиотеку pyvoip. З первого взгляда она имела весь нужный функционал, но..
Начав писать код и пробовать первые запуски выснилось что библиотека не поддерживает DIGEST авторизацию и OPTIONS запрос. Поискав решения в issues гитхаба библиотеки нашёл решение - установить дев версию!
Она уже имела "недостающие детали", но проблем с ней было ещё больше - код невероятно сырой. Я исправил основные проблемы и таки подключился к sip серверу, но опять ещё одно разочарование.. Не держится подключение с сервером и всё ещё имеет куча проблем в коде

После 5 дней постояного дебага, тестов и исправления чужого кода очень устал и начал искать иные решения так и не найшов, по этому пишу сюда, может кто нибудь имел дело с такого рода задачами.

Заранее спасибо за ответ!

Comment: рекомендую уходить в голый  ctypes)

Comment: хотя попробуй pjsua, обертка к сишной  pjsip

Comment: этот функционал надо было сделать буквально на вчера, по этому с нуля писать не буду)

Comment: так там работы добавится только  проставить типы.